# Will these microphone background nosie solutions work?

Tags: microphone, audio, noise, removal

I recently discovered that any microphone I plug in generates the same background noise. Some helpful users on Superuser pointed me towards buying a USB soundcard/Preamp to elminate this, and I've also considered recording from my phone (sounds silly) as the phone doesn't seem to have the noise problem, but I'd require a few cables and adapters. My other ideas are buying a pocket recording with a mic in, or a Headphone to USB converter. Would any of these solutions I have come up with work?

https://superuser.com/questions/1018311/white-noise-when-recording-microphone-muted-or-unmuted/1018553#1018553 - Super user post

Comment: What doesn't satisfy you about Tetsujin's answer over at SuperUser? A USB interface is the way to go. Of course a standalone field recorder also works, but it's obviously useful for different situations from a PC-based solution – you must know for yourself which is better for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I use an app to stream audio from my phone to the pc via WiFi (also supports micro-USB or Bluetooth) Could be a quick solution if you think your phone's good enough to record sound (mine barely is)